# What arguments to use in a Loess macro for Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have found a macro on a forum which is a smoothing filter called Loess for time-series data. However, I am unable to run the macro properly as I'm not sure what the arguments are. [Here](https://stuukznac-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/211506603_stu_ukzn_ac_za/EXYw_QUgF11Oq78CQ1ZIHAkBdGYYGHMyqngJy5qKilC88A?e=GVNSG0) is the data I want to smooth. The macro code is below:

```
Public Function Loess(x As Variant, y As Variant, xnew As Variant, alpha As Variant, lambda As Integer)
    Dim n As Integer
    n = x.Rows.count
    n2 = xnew.Rows.count
    Dim q As Variant
    q = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(alpha * n, 1)
    q = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(q, 1)
    q = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(q, n)
    Dim z() As Variant
    ReDim z(n2)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To n2 - 1
        Dim deltax() As Variant
        ReDim deltax(n)
        Dim j As Integer

        For j = 0 To n - 1
            deltax(j) = Abs(xnew(i + 1) - x(j + 1))
        Next j
        Dim qthdeltax As Variant

        qthdeltax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(deltax, q)

        Dim arg() As Variant
        ReDim arg(n)
        For j = 0 To n - 1
            arg(j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(deltax(j) / (qthdeltax * Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(alpha, 1)), 1)
        Next j
        Dim tricube() As Variant
        ReDim tricube(n)
        Dim count As Integer
        count = 0
        For j = 0 To n - 1
            tricube(j) = (1 - Abs(arg(j)) ^ 3) ^ 3
            If tricube(j) > 0 Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next j
        Dim weight() As Variant
        ReDim weight(count - 1)
        Dim count1, zeroes As Integer
        count1 = 0
        zeroes = 0
        For j = 0 To n - 1
            If tricube(j) > 0 Then
                weight(count1) = tricube(j)
                count1 = count1 + 1
            Else
                If count1 = 0 Then
                    zeroes = zeroes + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        Dim weightx(), weighty() As Variant
        ReDim weightx(count - 1), weighty(count - 1)
        For j = 0 To count - 1
            weightx(j) = x(zeroes + j + 1)
            weighty(j) = y(zeroes + j + 1)
        Next j
        Dim p() As Variant
        ReDim p(lambda + 1, lambda + 1)
        p = Least2(weightx, weighty, lambda, weight)
        z(i) = Polyval(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(p), xnew(i + 1))
    Next i
    Loess = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(z)
End Function
```

Comment: Does the website you took the macro from not explain how to use it? Are there any comments in the code?

Comment: Unfortunately, it was posted in the comments section of an old thread of the forum. So the OP would be unable to respond to any questions now

Comment: Here is a "computery" reference for the function (for python but has nice explanatory notes)  ( http://www.jtrive.com/loess-nonparametric-scatterplot-smoothing-in-python.html ). I note in your snippet: x,y are declared as `variant` and then values assigned using `x.Rows.count`. I infer that  x and y are columns or ranges being passed. So x and y are "all the points" (an array, not single value pairs). Another parameter description: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/53789/versions/5/previews/dataviz_toolbox/dvt/html/loess.html

Comment: To add to the previous comment, y and x represent the dependent and independent variables of the data used for fitting the Loess model, xnew represents the independent variable values for which the modelled values are determined, alpha is the "smoothing constant" (which controls the number of data points used for local fitting) and lambda is the degree of the locally fitted polynomial regression model (1 for linear, 2 for quadratic, etc). The function outputs the fitted dependent variable values corresponding to the independent variable values in xnew.